# Getting search bar to simultaneously work with another search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, filter, datatables

I built a DataTables table and it comes with its own search bar, but I'm not happy with its default location. It's a major headache to use CSS to move it anywhere outside of the table's div so I've decided to *link it with my own custom search bar*...i.e., typing in the custom search triggers the DataTables one. The end goal is to hide the DataTables search with the custom filter acting as the main one.

I know that I want the custom search to trigger on `.keypress()`, but other than that I don't know how to link the two searches together and how to get them to work simultaneously. I didn't see any info about doing to on SO (if there is, please point me in the right direction) or on the DT forums.

#### DataTable:

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        { data: "Titles" }, // populates col-2 column with docs
        { data: "Categories" } // hidden col-3 categories
        //{ data: "Blank" } // Use if necessary
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          data: "Path",
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
          targets: 0
        },
        { searchable: true, targets: [1], visible: false }, 
      ],
      data: tableRes,
      // fields: [{ label: "My Favorites:", name: "faves", type: "checkbox" }],
      language: { searchPlaceholder: "Search All Documents" },
      order: [],
      pageLength: 500,
      pagingType: "full_numbers",
      responsive: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: 450
    });
```

#### Custom searchbar functionality:

```
$("#searchbar").keypress(function() {
   // stuff here ///////
  //// not sure what //
  console.log("Handler for .keypress() called");
})
```

#### DataTables CSS:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    /* visibility: hidden;  */
}
```

#### Custom searchbar:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input 
      type="search" 
      class="form-control" 
      id="searchbar" 
      placeholder="Search All Documents...">
</div>
```

Comment: `var oTable = $('#km-table-id').DataTable();   
$('#searchbar').on("input",function(){
      oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})`

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, I got it working. I didn't realize there was a detailed thread about linking the searchbars.